# disable "add existing item" feature

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have been working on a visual studio 2010 copernicus project and recently wanted to disable the "Add-> Existing Item" feature in the context menu of the project node in solution explorer as it is of no use for me. I looked at a lot of code and found properties of most of the other context menu items but not this. How can I disable this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Travel to tools > customize > commands > context menu > Project and Solution Context Menus | Project | Add

Select 'add existing item' and then click delete

The trick was probably to know to look for the `| Add` entry. Other than that it's pretty obvious.

Comment: What didn't work? You found your way to the "add existing item" entry and clicked delete, and it still showed up in the context menu? You couldn't find the entry at all? There's no delete button?

Comment: Yeah, I deleted the "add existing item" entry but it still showed up in the context menu

Comment: Verify you're even in the right neighborhood by removing some other things and seeing if they disappear. What's copernicus? Maybe it's a project type add-in that is in a different commands namespace or managing itself.